# how to prevent entering and pasting single and double quotes inside cleditor?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

how to prevent entering and pasting single and double quotes inside cleditor?
how to prevent entering and pasting single and double quotes inside cleditor?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $prevent_single_double_quote = function(e){
    var element=e;
    setTimeout(function () { element.val(element.val().replace(/['"]/g, "")); }, 1);
    }
    $('textarea').on('paste', function () {
    $prevent_single_double_quote($(this));
    });
    $('textarea').on('keyup', function () {
    $prevent_single_double_quote($(this));
    });
    $('input').on('paste', function () {
    $prevent_single_double_quote($(this));
    });
    $('input').on('keyup', function () {
    $prevent_single_double_quote($(this));
    });
    $('.scle').on('keyup', function () {
    $prevent_single_double_quote($(this));
    });
});
</script>

 <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="block block-fill-white" id="mailcontent">
                   <div class="content np" id="mailcontent">
                        <textarea class="scle" name="mailcontent" id="mailcontent"></textarea>
                   </div>
               </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Let used add it. Handle it at server side..`addslashes` or `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: i need jquery function

Comment: Why do I have a horrible feeling that this is a **very broken** attempt at preventing code injection?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $prevent_single_double_quote = function(e) {
        var element = e;
        setTimeout(function() {
            var regexFormat = /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/;
            var text = element.val();
            if(!regexFormat.test(text)){
                //if contains single or double quotes.
                text = text.substring(0, (text.length-1));
            }
            element.val(text);
        }, 1);
    };
    $('textarea').on('change', function() {
        $prevent_single_double_quote($(this));
    });
    $('textarea').on('keyup', function() {
        $prevent_single_double_quote($(this));
    });
    $('input').on('change', function() {
        $prevent_single_double_quote($(this));
    });
    $('input').on('keyup', function() {
        $prevent_single_double_quote($(this));
    });
    $('.scle').on('keyup', function() {
        $prevent_single_double_quote($(this));
    });
});
```

Hope this might work!.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one, This solution is to prevent double quotes and single quotes while entering and pasting.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$prevent_single_double_quote = function(e) {
    var element = e;
    setTimeout(function() {
        var regexFormat = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\[\]\$\!\#\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\+\=\-\;\:\,\.\?\@\_\' ]*$/;
        var text = element.val();
        if(!regexFormat.test(text)){
            //if contains single or double quotes.
            text = text.substring(0, (text.length-1));
        }
        element.val(text);
    }, 1);
};
$('textarea').on('change', function() {
    $prevent_single_double_quote($(this));
});
$('textarea').on('keyup', function() {
    $prevent_single_double_quote($(this));
});
$('input').on('change', function() {
    $prevent_single_double_quote($(this));
});
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
    $prevent_single_double_quote($(this));
});
$('.scle').on('keyup', function() {
    $prevent_single_double_quote($(this));
});
$( "input" ).bind( 'paste',function()
 {
 var txtbx = $(this);
     setTimeout(function()
     { 
        //get the value of the input text
        var data= $( txtbx ).val() ;
        //replace the special characters to '' 
        var dataFull = data.replace(/((?<![\\])['"])((?:.(?!(?<![\\])\1))*.?)/gi, '');
        //set the new value of the input text without special characters
        $(txtbx).val(dataFull);
     });

  });
  });
```

See example here : https://jsfiddle.net/Shalitha/nfovt6bz/26/